# Changing WCF Reference Url .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, .net-core

I am attempting to integrate a Web Service into my project, but the problem is I will need to handle this Web Service for multiple environments. I'm using Visual Studios `Connected Services` tool to connect my service to my project. This auto generates me a `ConnectedServices.json` file that looks something like this:

```
"ProviderId": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ConnectedService.Wcf",
  "Version": "15",
  "ExtendedData": {
    "inputs": [
      "https://someurl/v3/GetUrl-dev.svc"
    ],
    "collectionTypes": [
      "System.Array",
      "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2"
    ],
    "namespaceMappings": [
      "*, GetUrl"
    ],
```

The problem is that I need to use both a `Dev` and a `Prod` environment in my project so I need to be able to reference both Web Services that have the same methods, just one has the `Prod` Reference Url `https://someurl/v3/GetUrl-Prod.svc`.

I've tried to Google it and look here as well but the solutions are mostly for ASP.NET applications, mine is a AWS Lambda project so these solutions don't fit me.

I have tried to add the endpoint explicitly like;

`var client = new GetUrlContractClient(new BasicHttpBinding(), new Endpoint("https://someurl/v3/GetUrl-Prod.svc");`

An exception gets thrown for including `https://` and says that it expects `http://` so I remove that and then the Web Service fails. I have also looked into modifying that JSON file on runtime, but it seems like a bad idea.

Is there a "standard practice" when it comes to using multiple environments with Connected Services on .Net Core?

Comment: _"it expects http://"_ - could that be because you're using a `BasicHttpBinding`?

Comment: @stuartd I don't think that is the issue but that gives me an idea for the Security Mode for the binding...

Comment: @stuartd I believe adding `new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport)` worked for me, can you please answer this so I can mark it?

Comment: you can answer your own question on SO, which seems appropriate here?

Comment: Where does this solution code exist? I also created my web service connections via the wizard, so I do not see where this `var client = new GetUrlContractClient(new BasicHttpBinding(), new Endpoint("https://someurl/v3/GetUrl-Prod.svc");` would be placed

Comment: @JamesHurley It would be placed wherever in code you need to use your client.

Comment: I never use the client in that way--I found a differ solution, the "preferred" solution is to extend the ConfigureEndpoint class from the auto generated Reference.cs class and change the endpoint there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So as it seems this was the correct way to go about it **but** in the `BasicHttpBinding` constructor you have to explicitly say that it is `BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport` and now it is working for me!